# How to check state Changing of CheckBox in android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to check if my Checkboxes are checked to change some values.
I got the answer for radioButton which is inserted to a RadioGroup and we can simply use :

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    { . . . } 
}
```

i'm looking for something like this ,However this approach is differ from Checkboxes because there is no widget like CheckboxGroup to use setOnCheckedChangeListener On it .

For example i have checkbox1 and checkbox2. how can i get as long as these two checkboxes are checked to changing some value like :

```
if(checkbox1==isChecked && checkbox2==isChecked)
//Do sth ...
else 
//Do sth Different
```

EDIT : Maybe i could not explain my problem perfectly , this is just like question below but for Checkboxes
[How to check state Changing of Radio Button android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678797/how-to-check-state-changing-of-radio-button-android)

Comment: you mean `if(checkbox1.isChecked() && checkbox2.isChecked())`

Comment: yes , but I want to use them in a different function , may globally access to this checkboxes @Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757252/how-to-check-state-changing-of-checkbox-in-android/45757418#comment78471869_45757252) you can use `checkboxRef.isChecked()`

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked() && checkbox2.isChecked()){

}
else{

}
```

> but I want to use them in a different function , may globally access
>   to this checkboxes

You can use [`sharedPreference`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and with a utility class to store the state of your checkbox.

[SharedPreferences helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912227/sharedpreferences-helper-class)

Answer (score 0):

This is way to check which checkbox is checked..

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked())
{
//means checkbox1 is checked...
}else
{
//means checkbox2 is checked...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an event listener to detect when a change is made you can use:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {     
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        //Code here
 } } );
```

On the other hand if you want to check if it is checked you can use:

```
if(checkbox.isChecked()){
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer , first of all I need to set onclick attribute as the same for all of the checkboxes , and check my Needed for approach desire output in the onClick Function,

Xml:

```
  <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/c1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:id="@+id/c2"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:id="@+id/c3"/>
```

JavaCode:

```
public void func(View view) {


    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c1);
    CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c2);
    CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c3);

    if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked() && (!checkBox3.isChecked()))
    {
        Next = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Next = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()){
                }

            }
        });
```